# How to auto generate an attribute in DynamoDBMapper from the values of other attributes of an item

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Let's say a Student table has the following attributes id, course_code, joining_year, admission_number. Student id is auto-generated based on the other attributes {course_code}_{joining_year}_{admission_number} of this pattern. Can this be done using AWS DynamoDBMapper @DynamoDBAutoGenerated? If so how? or is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done because the auto generator api doesn’t allow you to introspect any other fields in the POJO. However you can get the results you want by making `getStudentId()` compute the value using the other fields in the POJO.

For example:

```
String getStudentId() {
    if (this.studentId == null) {
        this.studentId = String.format("%s_%s_%s", this.courseCode, this.joiningYear, this.admissionNumber);
    }
    return this.studentId;
}
```